# Unable to connect with empty password after password lost

Tags: password, proxmox

I own a server hosted in OVH and running Proxmox.

Unfortunately, I lost root password. I followed the instructions given on [that page](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Debian_reset_root_password) (the method 2 because I have no access to grub, as proposed in method 1) thanks to the rescue mode offered by OVH.

But, once the server restarted on his own hard drive, I'm unable to connect to the server with an empty password, the error is "Permission denied".

Have you got an idea?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: are you trying to connect after reboot by ssh?

Comment: No, it's a reboot hard.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to mean if you were trying to connect by ssh with empty password after you set the empty pass in /etc/passed. If yes, edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and enable empty password login.

Comment: Oh, sorry for my misunderstanding. Yes, I do try to connect by ssh but the option PermitEmptyPassword is already set to yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what exactly prohibits you to login with empty password, you could try and insert this instead:

```
$6$G.0wb3Gq$sc5whcSnWS0oswvsoSNyCSE/12VzmZ5LeSdP6SAUD6g9i1VyjYMKJGFqfspGGrwmr3t4i4BZcx/MyR4CU.FLd/
```

It should allow you to login with pass123 as password, obviously you should change it afterwards.